# connect to two domain controllers on two NICs

Tags: windows-7, lan, windows-domain

I have a computer that sits on two LANs, each with its own NIC.  Each LAN has a domain controller.  This computer logs in to windows using the domain controller on LAN A, after logged in I would like to log in and access LAN B's networks, printers and file shares.

This is a Windows 7 machine, and I have accounts on both domain controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows *computer* can only be *joined* to one Active Directory domain.  However, this does not limit you to one AD domain's resources.  Since your other NIC is connected to the other AD domain's network, those resources might still be available to you.  If there is a [trust relationship](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977993.aspx) between the two AD domains, those resources might be immediately available to you.  However, since you said they are two different LAN's, it *sounds* like they are completely segregated.  You would have to check with your system administrator.  A more likely solution would be for you to have an AD account on the other domain.  Since your machine is not joined to that domain, you will be prompted for logon credentials when you initially connect to a domain resource.  Once those credentials are provided, you would have access to those resources, based on domain policies, for as long as your session is connected.

Comment: This makes sense, is there a way to change your password on the second domain controller, the one I am NOT using to login to Windows?

Comment: @Michael if your password expires, or is marked to be changed, it will prompt you the next time you logon with credentials.  Also, you can follow these [instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149176).